# How to change the style plotting in octave with pkg symbolic?

Tags: octave

I'm trying to chance the style plotting for symbolic functions
But I can't , to plot those functions I used the command `ezplot`, but not work like  command `plot`
In `plot` I put the style of line after function, of course defined before, values of variable used in function.
Now I want to do the same with symbolic functions, I want to put a different style like in `plot`.
I hope that someone can help me with a explicit example, please.

Answer (score 1):

`plot` is a high level function that accepts the line styles as additional input. In order to alter the appearance of `ezplot` you'll want to specify [the `line` properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Line-Properties.html) using the graphics handle that is returned by `ezplot`

```
h = ezplot('x^2');
set(h, 'LineStyle', ':', 'Marker', '*', 'Color', 'r')
```

Comment: Not work, do you have another idea?,   I wrote that,             pkg load symbolic, syms x, h=ezplot('x^2'), set(h,':','*','r'),   and octave return me. error: set: inválido handle (=-1.58641)